# Use of undeclared type 'KeyType' in Dictionary extension (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift-extensions

With the beta 5 changes I'm running into an error related to KeyType and ValueType in the extension below.

```
extension Dictionary {

    func filter(predicate: (key: KeyType, value: ValueType) -> Bool) -> Dictionary {
        var filteredDictionary = Dictionary()

        for (key, value) in self {
            if predicate(key: key, value: value) {
                filteredDictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        }

        return filteredDictionary
    }
}
```

I might be missing something, but I can't seem to find any related changes in the release notes and I know that this worked in beta 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Dictionary` declaration has changed to use just `Key` and `Value` for its associated types instead of `KeyType` and `ValueType`:

```
// Swift beta 3:
struct Dictionary<KeyType : Hashable, ValueType> : Collection, DictionaryLiteralConvertible { ... }

// Swift beta 5:
struct Dictionary<Key : Hashable, Value> : CollectionType, DictionaryLiteralConvertible { ... }
```

So your extension just needs to be:

```
extension Dictionary {

    func filter(predicate: (key: Key, value: Value) -> Bool) -> Dictionary {
        var filteredDictionary = Dictionary()

        for (key, value) in self {
            if predicate(key: key, value: value) {
                filteredDictionary.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
            }
        }

        return filteredDictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a single resource that documents all of the breaking changes in each build of Xcode? Googling every single error is driving me nuts.

Comment: The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) for each beta have a section that covers the changes, but not in very much detail. There seem to be a few bloggers picking up the beta changes beat - Erica Sadun and Airspeed Velocity both had posts about the changes, among others, I'm sure.